# Drools Upgrade from 5.4 to 6.2 not working in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, tomcat7, java-7, drools

We are using eclipse Kepler Service Release 2,Tomcat 7.0.64,JDk1.7. We were previoulsy using the drools 5.4.0 and now we have upgraded the drools 6.2.0. We have added the below files in the build path and web application lib folder as part of the upgrade.

1.drools-compiler-6.2.0.Final-redhat-4.jar
2.drools-core-6.2.0.Final-redhat-4.jar
3.ecj-4.3.1.jar
4.drools-templates-6.2.0.Final-redhat-4.jar
5.kie-api-6.2.0.Final-redhat-4.jar
6.kie-internal-6.2.0.Final-redhat-4.jar
7.knowledge-api-6.2.0.Final-redhat-4.jar
8.mvel2-2.2.4.Final-redhat-1.jar
9.protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar
10.slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar
11.slf4j-simple-1.6.4.jar
12.xstream-1.4.7.jar
13.xmlpull-1.1.3.1.jar
14.antlr-runtime-3.5.jar

My tomcat and webspplication was working fine with the previous version of drools. But the issue started to occur once I introduced the above files.From the below error I understand that some jar files are getting conflicted but I don't know which file is getting conflicated and how to find that out.

When ever I start my tomcat web server I am getting the below exception.

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.CompilationResult.getProblems()[Lorg/eclipse/jdt/core/compiler/IProblem;
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler$2.acceptResult(JDTCompiler.java:354)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:480)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:425)
>     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:298)   at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:277)    at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:265)    at
>   org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:564)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:302)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:329)
>     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Jun 07, 2016 11:56:57 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke SEVERE:
>   Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [] threw
>   exception [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.CompilationResult.getProblems()[Lorg/eclipse/jdt/core/compiler/IProblem;]
>   with root cause java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.CompilationResult.getProblems()[Lorg/eclipse/jdt/core/compiler/IProblem;
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler$2.acceptResult(JDTCompiler.java:354)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:480)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:425)
>     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:298)   at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:277)    at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:265)    at
>   org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:564)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:302)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:329)
>     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Can anybody please help me in resolving the above issue?

Note: we are not using Maven in our project set up.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using maven, then it may get very complicated to get all the necessary dependencies.

My suggestion is to create a very simple maven project with the dependencies you need (kie-api, drools-compiler, drools-core, drools-templates) and then do a:

```
mvn dependency:copy-dependencies
```

The command above will create a directory under `target` called `dependencies` where you will find all the `.jar` files that are required by the Drools artifacts you are using.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thanks Esteban for your reply. I have figured out that ecj-4.3.1.jar is causing the problem because If i removed the jar from WEB-INF/lib folder then it is able to load the jsp pages. But in this case it is not able to load my KnowledgeBaseRepository at runtime due to the absence of the jar file.But still I will follow your approach to indetify the exact set of dependencies.

Comment: Esteban yesterday I followed your approach and checked all the . All the jar files I have listed in the question are the dependencies that is been listed by the maven as well.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have multiple `ecj` versions in your classpath? According to your stacktrace, the problem is being caused by jasper trying to use a version of `ecj` that was not the one it was expecting.

Comment: Esteban Thanks for your reply.I can see the class org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.CompilationResult inside the two jar files one inside the jar files ecj-4.3.1.jar , jasper-compiler-jdt.jar. Is that causing the issue , if yes then how to resolve the issue?

Comment: Esteban,You are right about multiple ecj version.I have also checked the tomcat lib folder it contains the ecj-4.2.2.jar. Afterwards I removed the ecj-4.3.1.jar and jasper-compiler-jdt.jar from WEB-INF/lib folder. But still the issue remains the same .

Comment: You will need to find out a way to normalize that. Check if there is a jasper version that depends on a ecj version that is compatible with Drools.